# multi currency implementation

Tags: next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

i'm trying to implement multi currency in my NextJS based website. i have APIs which accept currency_id as parameter and based on that return currency symbol and converted amount. i would like to setup a dropdown in site header and when user set a currency, need to pass the currency_id to all apis like product list, product details etc..untill user switch currency. the issue i faced is padding the currency id between client component and server component. is that any solution for this?

tried to store currency id in localStorage and sessionStorage, but can't accessible that from server component.